# Get files in directory but not subdirectory

Tags: bash

I want to get all files in a directory but not in any subdirectories in that directory. So far i am using;

```
file=(path/to/my/files/*)

for f in ${files[@]}; do ...
```

Comment: Did you try using `find` ?

Comment: Maybe some day, `bash` will get `zsh`-style glob qualifiers: `files=(path/to/my/files/*(.))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper error free way of doing it using `GNU` find would be something like

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do

    # Your script/command(s) goes here

done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

The `man find` says the following about the `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` fields

```
-maxdepth levels
          Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the command line arguments.  -maxdepth 0
           means only apply the tests and actions to the command line arguments.

-mindepth levels
          Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative integer).  -mindepth 1 means process all files except the command line arguments.
```

So ideally a `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1` would not go beyond the search of files at more than one level i.e. limiting within the current directory. And the `-print0` flag takes care of handling files with special characters.

Answer (score 2):

Skip subdirectories within the loop:

```
for file in path/to/my/files/*; do
    [[ -d $file ]] && continue
    # do other stuff here
done
```

It's not amazingly efficient but you can build an array of the files like this:

```
files=()
for file in path/to/my/files/*; do
    [[ -d $file ]] || files+=( "$file" )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your homework before asking :)

If you want to get just the files, It is as simple as that:

```
find <directory_name> -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

If you want to get directories under a directory (just 1 level:

```
find <directory_name> -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

You get the point

In a bash script (Thanks to @chepner for his notes):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "$file" 
done
```

Comment: ...and how do I get the results of find into a variable I can loop?

Comment: Easily: `#!/bin/bash
my_files=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`

for file in $my_files; do
    echo $file 
done
`

Comment: I added the response to the original answer for your convinience

Comment: its not an error, i just get a long concatenated output of the files even if i use `\n` or `printf`

Comment: The backticks are generally compatible with older shells, so they are considered more "portable". I suppose that's the case for you?

Comment: Yea backticks work nicely. Still learning shell so thought Id ask anyway. Thanks

Comment: If directories contain any whitespace or glob characters then this solution will break.

Comment: If directories contain any whitespace or glob characters (I wonder why someone would name his directories this way), one should hust enclose add double quotes in `"$my_files"`

Comment: @anubhava I m not sure whether your comment adds any value to the original question, but to address your need of naming your files in whatever is needed to trick my original bash script, I updated my answer.

Comment: Actually a simple for loop using glob like in answer by @TomFenech is much better than `find` here.

Comment: Much better in terms of efficiency? I don't argue that its a fine solution, but I don't think that this gives a valid reason for you to vote down my answer. Anyways, it's your call

Comment: You can't just put double quotes around the variable `"$my_files"` otherwise your loop will only iterate once.

Comment: @TomFenech have you ran my script and it ran only once? What's the effect of setting `IFS=$'\n'` ?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to permanently change `IFS` like that but I don't see how it will affect the way the loop works. `for` expects a list of words, but if you put double quotes around the variable then it will only receive one word.

Comment: I don't permanently change anything. This is valid just until the end of the bash script. I won't explain the IFS functionality, read the documentation. Or maybe check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping . You don't even bother running the script to confirm it works.

Comment: I think that it's fair to use the word permanent in this context to refer to anything that lasts the full length of the script. Your loop only runs for one iteration. You can confirm this by changing the echo to `echo "$file here"` and you will only see the word "here" once. As an aside, you're missing double quotes on that line in your answer.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the proper way to iterate over the output of `find`.

Comment: @chepner that was really helpful. It seems that I was wrong on handling these special-character cases. I ll update my answer for the sake of correctness